# Validation loss way greater than 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm using Keras to classify EEG signals, which are processed with different feature extraction methods. I constantly run into an issue, where the [Validation loss is way greater than 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oaYz.png) regardless of the method used. I am using Sparse Categorical Crossentropy as a loss function, and the ANN is a traditional resolution neural network with 50 layers (ResNet50). The validation set is made by choosing random samples from the training set. Hope someone has an idea and I really hope it is caused by a silly mistake.

Comment: The problem is that your training features are not generalizing well to the validation set. Recall what the point of validation is. You are updating the coefficients of your network during training, then, you are showing it some unseen data, and seeing how well those coefficients predict some data it has not seen.

Comment: @JohnStud OP said their test set is a random sample of their training dataset

Comment: Ok with this in mind, then what is the training loss?

Comment: @JohnStud If I understand correctly (I did not write the whole code since it is part of a BCI system), our training and validation work the following: We have a set of labeled data, and we set a % number for validation. The randomly selected samples get excluded from the training set, and at the end, fed as validation data. Hope I got your question right.

Comment: Yep, what is the loss observed during training? Is it poor too?

Comment: @JohnStud it looks like it is overfitting, since the training loss is decreasing as it should, here is the "log" https://prnt.sc/xg1e2i

Comment: Interesting. You need to add some regularization to your training pipeline, either in the form of L2, dropout, or both. It is curious that if you are using data in your validation set that also comes from training set, that it is not also able to pretty much perfectly predict those. Are you failing to do some sort of transformation on that the data thats being injected for validation?